# spark multi table join failed in last stage

Tags: apache-spark, join

I have a spark job written in sparksql, version 1.6.2, which need to joins 23 tables nearly the same size.

Each table are generated from the same source table, so they almost have same size (All of them have around 5514319 rows, the source table csv is around 1.5GB). All of these tables are join on the same column, and most of values in this column is unique (no more than 7 duplicates in the whole column). However the key column is in string format instead of number.

I need to join these 23 tables and pick one or two column from each table and save it using saveAsTable and

My job is now always frozen in the last stage, out of the 200 task the first 199 taks are able to finish within 5 to 10 minutes but the last one never finished and there is only one executor working on it.

It shows the symptom of skew data, but how can I tackle it?

[image]create hive parquet table.

I'm thinking separate these 23 joins into separate stages, but will that really help?

Comment: Sounds like "and most of values in this column is unique (no more than 7 duplicates in the whole column)" is not what really happens there. Start with double checking the data. Maybe nulls are skewing the things? And what type of join do you use? Inner? Outer? Left/Right?

Comment: It is using inner join

Comment: Providing sample code will help tackling exact issue. However, in general- Is your data partitioned? or partition-able? Partitions reduce the query scan time. If data is not partitioned, partition it on predicate columns (`where` clause or `on` clause). Another suggestion could be vectorization. Vectorized query execution improves join operation performance by performing them in batches of 1024 rows at once instead of a single row each time.